# Prove the following provided $f'(c)$ exists

Tags: limits, derivatives

If $f'(c)$ exists, prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to c}\frac{xf(c)-cf(x)}{x-c}=f(c)-f'(c)$

How do you prove this? Directly applying limit rules, it seems to simply to $f(c)$ in my attempt. Using L'Hopital's Rule renders it to $\frac{f(c)}{c-c}$.

Though, it's quite clear I've been doing something wrong. Help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how you applied L'Hopital's Rule, but it doesn't render to $\frac{f(c)}{c-c}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: we have

$$\frac{xf(c) - cf(x)}{x-c} = \frac{x f(c) - xf(x) +xf(x) - cf(x)}{x-c} = f(x) - x\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$$

In fact, the limit is $f(c) - cf'(c)$ rather than $f(c) - f'(c)$.